# E/ReactNativeJS: Error: Failed to create a new instance, the native initializer function does not exist

Tags: react-native, android-studio

After uninstall of react-native-mmkv module, I get this error when running android app through android studio:

E/ReactNativeJS: Error: Failed to create a new MMKV instance, the native initializer function does not exist. Is the native MMKV library correctly installed? Make sure to disable any remote debugger (e.g. Chrome) to use JSI!
E/ReactNativeJS: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r(d[3]).storage')

I run the app on iPhone simulator/device with no errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get this after installing react-native-mmkv and its pods on ios

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the app. It should work fine.

```
yarn android
```